# Create Google Client ID for Cloud Delivery

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cloud

This question is in regard to manually creating a [Google Analytics Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId).

I am attempting trigger data to Google Analytics from the Cloud. Since the Google Analytics JS code will not be running on the site where the event data initially resides, I need to be able to create a Client ID and apply that ID to an object of data that gets sent to the Cloud for processing and triggering of data to Google Analytics.

My problem is that I can create an ID (both 1234567890.1234567890 and ac813ca3-3236-457a-9edd-fe0b9965f7f6 formats), and the trigger runs successfully, but Google isn't showing they received the data. The real-time reports and the general reporting show 0 hits.

So my question is: do I have to ping Google to, in a sense, seed or initialize the user? Meaning only Google can supply the client ID? Meaning, in more detail, I can create one of the IDs above and trigger that ID to Google but since they didn't create it and initialize the user they just ignore the hit?

Thanks for any thoughts/guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit data to Google Analytics, you use the credentials they provide you. I think you should be asking [Is there any way to post events to Google Analytics via Server-Side API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9503329/3771976).

Comment: Heh, I've looked at that article 15 times today and just be clicking it one more time I found the issue. I was using the Event Tracking hit type instead of the Page Tracking hit type. Since I wasn't passing a Category/Action/Label GA was rejecting it.